# Appium Flutter Driver | capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Flutter") fails

Tags: java, flutter, appium

I have created an automation project to test a flutter app using appium flutter driver.
But I cannot use flutter driver.

My automation project does not detect automationName as flutter.
Even if I try driver.context("FLUTTER"); I get NoSuchContextException error.

```
service = AppiumDriverLocalService
                  .buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                          .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/bin/node"))
                          .withAppiumJS(
                                  new File("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
                          .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723));
    service.start();

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
          File appDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/app");
          File app = new File (appDir,"app-debug.apk");
          capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
          capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
          capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Flutter");
          capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.flutter_intellij_test");
     capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.example.flutter_intellij_test.MainActivity");

        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        
        find = new FlutterFinder(driver);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Appium server version is above [1.6](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/15172a9c298d2f307c87aa2a8746b02b51d215ab/CHANGELOG.md#changes-in-version-1160-from-1151)

There shouldn't be anything specific with Java client, just try to change your capabilities this way:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
File appDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/app");
File app = new File (appDir,"app-debug.apk");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Flutter");
capabilities.setCapability("retryBackoffTime", "500");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", <value from `adb devices`>);
driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(service.getUrl(), capabilities);
```

Next time post Appium server log :)

Comment: I am using Appium v1.19.0

Error:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Please update yout question with full stack trace. So far I can tell that you are able to create session, but not to find element